# JSON file creation with URL

Tags: flutter-http

I want to know how to create JSON file and where to create the URL in flutter. in all examples they are pasting the URL but i want to know where it from.

Comment: Can you try to be a bit more specific? It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: how to parse json data from some specific URL in dart?